# CSP vulnerablity : Wildcard Directive

Tags: asp.net, iis

When I am scanning my website I am getting vulnerablity CSP: Wildcard Directive.

This is my response header:

```
default-src 'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;script-src 'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https: ;style-src 'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;connect-src 'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;font-src 'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;img-src 'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;base-uri 'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;form-action 'none';frame-src 'self';frame-ancestors 'self'
```

(Broken-up for readability below):

```
default-src     'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;
script-src      'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;
style-src       'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;
connect-src     'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;
font-src        'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;
img-src         'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;
base-uri        'self' 'nonce-A1A858B312C6D596C4CA536BD2D20F67' https:;
form-action     'none';
frame-src       'self';
frame-ancestors 'self'
```

How to resolve that error?

Comment: Using `https:` as a `<source>` value means that _any_ website (served over `https://`) is valid, hence the wildcard warning.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to fix the CSP Wildcard Directive vulnerability, depending on the web application's requirements and security needs. Here are some best practices to follow:

> 1. Use a strict CSP header: A strict CSP header only allows specific content sources to be loaded by the web application, reducing the
>    attack surface. For example, consider the following CSP header:
>    Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
>    'unsafe-eval' https:; In this header, we only allow content to be
>    loaded from the same domain ('self'), allow inline scripts and styles
>    ('unsafe-inline'), and allow scripts to be executed ('unsafe-eval') on
>    the same domain. We also allow content to be loaded from HTTPS sources
>    (https:).
> 2. Use the nonce attribute: The nonce attribute is a random value that is generated by the server and included in the CSP header. It allows
>    inline scripts to be executed by the web application, but only if they
>    match the nonce value. This prevents attackers from injecting
>    malicious inline scripts into the web application. For example,
>    consider the following CSP header: Content-Security-Policy: script-src
>    'nonce-ABC123' https:; In this header, we only allow scripts to be
>    loaded from HTTPS sources (https:) and inline scripts that match the
>    nonce value (`'nonce-ABC123'`).
> 3. Use the sha256 attribute: The sha256 attribute is similar to the nonce attribute, but it allows specific inline scripts to be executed
>    based on their hash value. This is useful when the web application
>    needs to execute specific inline scripts that cannot be included in a
>    separate file. For example, consider the following CSP header:
>    Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-ABC123' https:; In this
>    header, we only allow scripts to be loaded from HTTPS sources (https:)
>    and inline scripts that have the hash value ABC123.
> 4. Avoid using the unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval directives: The unsafe-inline directive allows inline scripts and styles to be
>    executed by the web application, while the unsafe-eval directive
>    allows scripts to be executed from strings. These directives should be
>    avoided as they significantly increase the attack surface of the web
>    application.
> 5. Define specific content sources: When defining content sources in the CSP header, it is essential to be as specific as possible. For
>    example, instead of allowing content to be loaded from any domain (*),
>    we can define specific domains or subdomains that are trusted by the
>    web application. This reduces the attack surface and improves the
>    overall security of the application.

Comment: 1. Before making any changes to the CSP header, you must check the requirements of your web application. You need to ensure that the new CSP header does not break any functionality of your application. 2. Based on the needs of the web application, define strict CSP headers that only allow specific content sources to be loaded. 3. After implementing the new CSP header, you need to thoroughly test your web application to ensure that all functionality is working as expected. You can use your browser's developer tools to check for any CSP violations.